# PhpStorm Access localhost from android device

Tags: php, android, ip, localhost, phpstorm

I have installed phpStorm in my Windows computer.
And run a simple app and it appears that its working from chrome.

http://localhost:50172/untitled/demo.php

I am trying from yesterday to access it from android device
But can't and gave me this error :

`failed to connect to /192.168.1.45 (port 50172): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

When i Tried to access localhost from "xampp" my android device can access it!!

This is a printscreen from the configuration of another application :
[image]

Their is any error for configuring or any mistake im doing ?!

Comment: 'When i Tried to access localhost from "xampp" my android device can access it!! ' ????? What do you mean? You said you could not access it from your phone.

Comment: phpstorm can make localhost too but i need to use it. but when trying using xampp it worked so is it problem with phpstorm configuration as i think !!

Comment: How you created the server run on Phpstorm? Could you take a picture of your Phpstorm where you configure...?